# Docker Linking in C# - What is best way to discover Environmental Variables Injected Through Linking

Tags: c#, docker, dockerfile

So I am setting up a simple multi container application in C# with the following article [Dockerizing a Redis Service](https://docs.docker.com/examples/running_redis_service/)

I created my Redis image using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM        ubuntu:14.04
RUN         apt-get update && apt-get install -y redis-server
EXPOSE      6379
ENTRYPOINT  ["/usr/bin/redis-server"]
```

then I create my image using the following command

`docker build -t sample/redis`

and finally created my Redis container

`docker run -d --name redis sample/redis`

Then I am creating my web app container which just runs a simple Console application to run `Redis` using the following Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

EXPOSE 1234

ENTRYPOINT ["mono","/path/to/my/app/app.exe"]
```

Using this Dockerfile, I built the image...

`docker build -t sample/my-app-image`

and finally, I created the container with a link to the previously created `Redis` container.

`docker run --link redis:redis --name my-app-image -d -it sample/my-app-image`

and my app looks something like the following:

```
public class Program
{  
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        var path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REDIT_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR");
        IRedisCache cache = new RedisCache(path);
   }
}
```

Is using the `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(...)` correct to use to grab the linked information from the Redis container, or am I doing this completely wrong?

```
var path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REDIT_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR");
```

This doesn't seem like a very configurable approach. Any suggestions or modifications I should be making?